# Вращение части объекта в Blender

Tags: blender

Есть объект в виде карандаша и нужно, чтобы его грифельная часть вращалась по кругу,а основание,где ластик,оставалось на месте. Может можно как-то то через empty object сделать привязку к верхней части объекта и его анимировать на движение по кругу?

Answer (score 0):

В едит моде выделите несколько точек или полигонов, и выберите ось по которой будете вращать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же можно сменить точку вокруг которой будет происходить трансформация (обычно median point).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или совсем можете сделать грифель отдельным объектом (что кстати и рекомендую если Вы хотите в дальнейшем анимировать).

1. Зайдите в едит мод.
2. Выберите точки/полигоны которые хотите сделать отдельным объектом.
3. Нажимаете P (англ) -> Selection
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого выделаная область будет отдельным объектом, и делайте с им что хотите.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: Для избежения проблем
ПКМ по новому объекту, set origin -> origin to geometry

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ХмТак тогда же при анимации у меня будет двигаться только грифельная часть,а надо чтобы карандаш тоже был в движении.Вот пример того как должно происходить движение https://pin.it/4Vg6xan . Я же правильно понимаю, что здесь основание остаётся на месте, а верхняя часть двигается по окружности